# Books where gems fall from the sky and are used to focus magic

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic, elves

I read these books long ago and don’t remember the titles. Set in a fantasy world where an orphan boy is found by elves that live in a forest near a river. Everyday he has to put stones in the water and wrong them when wine comes out for the elves. Gems fall from the sky and the elves collect them and polish them to use as a focus for magic. Each gem has a different ability.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year/s did you read these books, and when do you think they might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about any of the covers?

Comment: I'd rather have a gem that makes books fall from the sky.

Comment: What does this mean: "Everyday he has to put stones in the water and wrong them when wine comes out for the elves."?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I'm guessing he was supposed to *wring* them, not "wrong" them.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stormlight_Archive

Comment: In those the gems don't fall from the sky - they are obtained through ... other means. Periodic storms roll through, and the lightning from the storms will charge up the gems. They are used for light and currency. And ... other things.

Comment: Any chance the answer I suggested is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 14):

There is a book called *[The Demon Awakens](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/529582.The_Demon_Awakens)*, by R.A. Salvatore.

Gems periodically fall from the sky like rain, but only on a specific island. A human religious order sets out to collect the gems every twenty years or so, each type of stone (emerald, amethyst, tiger-eye and so on) can be used for a different 'spell' or magical effect (for example, tiger-eye could heal injuries IIRC).

There *are* elves in this world but they have their own kind of magic that doesn't rely on the fallen gems. They *do* find a human orphan and take him in.

[image]